# PHP - 2d array json_encode not working properly?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to encode 2D array into JSON object, `json_encode` encoding the array successfully but not as I wanted.

This is my php code.

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $response[$row['tid']][$row['id']] = 
  new historylist($row['tid'],$row['id'],$row['uid'],$row['city'],$row['country'],$row['timestamp'],
       $row['domain'],$row['health'],$row['coordinates'],$row['destination'],$row['host']);
}

echo json_encode($response);
```

I am getting response as

```
{                        
 "tid": {               //json object start
         "subtid": {
            
        },
         "subtid": {
            
        }                  
     }                        //json object end
}
```

But I want array of subtid's like this

```
{
    "tid": [                  //json array start 
        {
                              //subtid object 1
        },
        {
                              //subtid object 2
       }
     ]                        //json array end
}
```

I guess I am making some silly mistakes, please let me know what I am missing

Comment: The way you would like the JSON is invalid, array values cannot have associative keys.

Comment: This is not a valid JSON

Comment: Ok, I got it, is there any way to eliminate keys?

Comment: Thanks @Dharman for the suggestion, I just copied the response JSON without checking. I have updated the question, I hope now I am more clear

Comment: @PritamPawade $response[$row['tid']][$row['id']] just remove `$row['id']` its always provide object n your need array so just put
`$response[$row['tid']][] = your other data process logic`

Answer (score 0):

Can you send simple data format from `$result->fetch_assoc()`
i can help you if i know the `$result->fetch_assoc()` data format

Comment: Thank you for your reply, But I figured it out please check comments of this question